# How do you return an embedded resource .aspx page via a httphandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Pop quiz hot shots...

I have a Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4 solution with 2 projects, The first project is a c# class library that contains a httphandler and a .aspx page. The .aspx page's build action has been set to "Embedded Resource".

The second project is an asp.net web application which references the first. The httphandler is wired up in the web.config.

I want the httphandler to serve the embedded .aspx page. How do I do this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is relevant:  http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/23/Loading-an-ASPNET-Page-Class-dynamically-in-an-HttpHandler

Answer (score 0):

.aspx is just a specialized kind of HttpHandler in .NET. Don't forget that.
Thus, .aspx files (ASP.NET Web Pages) actually have implemented `IHttpHandler` and they have `ProccessRequest` method. There are two ways to do this:

1. Based on dynamic compilation nature of Web Forms and markup vs. code-behind, if you want the markup of the page to be compiled dynamically and be executed, you have to extract the page (through code) and save it on the disk. This extraction process can take place on `Applciation_Start` event.
2. If you don't like the extraction method, don't forget that you can remove markup entirely and do everything in code-behind (just like PHP or old ASP or ASP.NET MVC). Also remember that your page is actually a **class** from the point of OOP. Thus simply instantiate it in your HttpHandler and call it's `ProcessRequest` method, passing the current `HttpContext` into it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is through a VirtualPathProvider, not a handler.  You can set up and register a virtual path provider to serve pages from an embedded resource (or database, web service, or anything else you can think of).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441